# It's the least I could do/have done

Tags: sentence-choice, politeness

Is

> It's the least I could do.

or

> It's the least I could have done.

better in response to "Thank you"?

I have seen people using "it's the least I could do" but personally, I feel "it's the least I could have done" is better.

Comment: the fewer syllables there are in a politeness formula, the better. Adding more attracts attention to something that's sposta just be ritual, and over fast.

Answer (score 1):

The following

> It was the least I could do

concisely and grammatically expresses the intended meaning, but also grammatical is

> It is the least I could have done

The sequence of tenses in

> It is the least I could do

might annoy a grammatical purist, but, with such formulaic and phatic language, no one is likely to notice, and anyone who does notice is very unlikely to care.

Comment: Google Books appears to have [*hundreds, if not **thousands***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+the+least+I+could+do%22) if hits for "was the least I could do", but there are [just 4 written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+the+least+I+could+have+done%22) of "was the least I could have done". And apparently nobody ever said ***is** the least I could have done* in print.